# c++ class function as argument to another class function

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, methods

I am trying to pass a templated member function of one class as an argument of a templated member function of another class. I've seen several examples of using function pointers, but i am trying to pass this function argument directly.

in

```
template <class Item> 
class MinHeap
```

i have the function

```
tempmlate <class Item>
template <class Process>
void inorder (Process f, const int index)
{
    if (index < size())
    {
        inorder(f, index*2 +1);
        f(data[index]);
        inorder(f, index*2 +2);
    }
}
```

and in

```
template<item>
class sequ
```

i have a function called

```
void insert(const Item& x);
```

I'm trying to do this in main:

```
MinHeap<int>* tree = new MinHeap<int>();
//insert some stuff
sequ<int>* s = new sequ<int>();
tree->inorder(s->insert);
```

but the last line gives me the error:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
tree->inorder(s->insert);
```

when i replace s->insert with the function, print

```
void print(int x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

it works fine.

how do i use a member function as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&sequ<int>::insert` gives you a pointer to the the member function `insert` of the `sequ<int>` class. However, to call a member function you also need an instance of the class. Said another way, you cannot perform `f(data[index]);` in the `inorder` function because you need an object instance to call the `f` member function.

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    void barFn(const std::string& data) { std::cout << "Bar<T>::barFn: " << data << "\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : mData{ "Hello World" } {}

    template<typename C, typename F>
    void fooFn(C* instance, F memFn, size_t n)
    {
        (instance->*memFn)(mData[n]);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> mData;
};

int main()
{
    Bar<int> bar;
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.fooFn(&bar, &Bar<int>::barFn, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
Bar<T>::barFn: Hello World
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/TmXJrx)